# elixir GenStage consumer min_demand

Tags: elixir, genstage

There is a project with genstage.

Producer A, producer-consumer B, and consumer C.

B requests events one at A (min_demand: 0, max_demand: 1).

```
{:producer_consumer, nil, subscribe_to: [{Grub.Producer, max_demand: 1, min_demand: 0}]}
```

C requests several events from B (min_demand: 25, max_demand: 50).

```
workers = for id <- 1..count do
  {:"Elixir.Grub.Worker#{id}", max_demand: 50, min_demand: 25}
end
{:consumer, {in_process_queue, errors_queue}, subscribe_to: workers}
```

But in fact, C receives and processes data one at a time (I see this from the application log).

How to make C process data in batches?

Answer (score 1):

GenStage do not cache data on it's own. So what you need to do is to cache data in producer-consumer [like it is documented](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/0.14.0/GenStage.html#module-buffering-events).

Comment: thanks, but here I see only buffering in the producer, in which you can track in handle_demand that events are not enough to meet the demand. But how to do it in producer-consumer, in which there is no handle_demand, but there is handle_events?